# How to quickly power off Android TV Box with remote control?

Tags: android, xml, android-tv, power-management

I bought the MX10 Android TV Box for my elderly parents and want to make it as simple as possible for them to operate. One of the things that they always have problems with is shutting the box down properly. Currently, a short press of the physical remote control power button puts the box to sleep. Is there a way to get rid of the sleep mode and just automatically fully shutdown the box anytime they press power? To currently shutdown, they need to do a long press of the power button which is then followed by a prompt asking "Do you want to shutdown" and then they have to press a couple more times to click 'OK' which is more complicated than they need it to be. The box appears to have root priveliges so is there a simple code I can add to 'build.prop' so that they can completely shutdown the box with one quick press of the remote power button (rather than it going to sleep)? I have tried 'poweroff.doubleclick=0' and that had no effect so am hoping there's some code that will work?

Comment: Maybe this is a question for https://superuser.com/? In any case, isn't it worse to shut it down every time? I mean, regarding user-experience-wise. Since it's an Android device, if you shut it down, when you turn it back on it will take a long time in a loading screen

Comment: It causes big problems in 'sleep' mode when they don't fully shutdown as it wakes the TV up every so often when they are watching something else. So ideally it would be good to completely shutdown with one quick press of the power button rather than the long press + extra clicks.